# Making execution of Python script fool-proof beyond adding shebang

Tags: design, python, gui, operating-systems, cross-platform

Assume that a Python package (available via PyPI) is too difficult for novice users to utilize. Specifically, typing `python2 path_to_package/start_GUI.py` in the command line, which opens a TKinter GUI, is too hard for many users. Instead, users would like to simply double-click on the file `start_GUI.py`, irrespective of the operating system they are on.

Beyond placing a shebang (i.e., `#!/usr/bin/env python2`) at the very top of the Python script `start_GUI.py`, how else can I make it easier for users to execute it?

**Linux/OSX**:

Users on Linux/OSX could double-click `start_GUI.py` if they first changed its file permissions (i.e., `chmod +X start_GUI.py`). Is it possible to change the file permissions of `start_GUI.py` during the installation of the package via `setup.py`?

**Windows**:

Users on Windows could double-click a batch file (e.g., `start_GUI.bat`), which in turn calls `start_GUI.py`. Minimal example of `start_GUI.bat`:

```
ECHO ON
REM A batch script to execute the GUI
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path_to_python\Python27
python path_to_package\start_GUI.py
PAUSE
```

Can I have this batch file written during the installation of the package via `setup.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users should not have to write any launcher scripts, which is why `setuptools` can create them for you with the `entry_points` key. For example:

```
setup(
  ...,
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
      'myprogram=mypackage:main',
     ],
  },
)
```

This would create an executable `myprogram` in a format appropriate for the target operating system that basically does:

```
import sys
from mypackage import main

sys.exit(main())
```

For further info, read [Automatic Script Creation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in the setuptools docs.

Comment: You read my mind. That was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!